# Cloned iOS app repository builds but crashes with error. Error is not on the developer's machine

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, git, cocoapods

I have a bit of a unique problem. I have been tasked with getting my company's iOS app running on my Mac. But after it finishes building, I get an error with one of the pods called SideMenuSwift that crashes the app. The weird part of this situation is, the app runs perfectly fine on the laptop where it was written. I cannot figure out what is different about my local repository or environment compared to the developer. The only difference I have been able to find is on the developer's machine, some of the folders inside of the project directory contain a DS_STORE whereas mine do not.

This is the error I get in the console in xcode:

> SideMenuSwift/SideMenuController.swift:172: Fatal error: [SideMenuSwift] `menuViewController` or `contentViewController` should not be nil.

Steps I have taken to set up the repo on my machine:

1. Cloned the repository with `git clone project_link`
2. ran `pod install`
3. ran `pod upgrade`
4. opened the repository in Xcode by running `open project_name.xcworkspace`

What I have tried:

1. I made sure that I have the same version of all the pod files, CocoaPods, Swift, and Xcode as the developer's laptop.
2. I made sure that I am on the same branch and on the same commit as the working version on the developer's laptop.
3. I checked the .gitignore and made sure that all the files in my directory are the same as in the developer's directory.
4. I followed the [docs](https://github.com/kukushi/SideMenu/tree/master), added the function below to initialize the ViewControllers in my SceneDelegate.swift file, and found the appropriate view controllers for menuViewController and contentViewController

   ```
      import UIKit
      import SideMenuSwift


      class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

          var window: UIWindow?

          @objc func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication) {
                  let contentViewController = myContentViewController()
                  let menuViewController = myMenuViewController()

                  window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
                  window?.rootViewController = SideMenuController(contentViewController: contentViewController,
                  menuViewController: menuViewController)

                  window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
                  return true
              }
          // Other stuff
   ```
5. Loaded an older commit in Xcode
6. Built the app for iPhone 14, iPhone 15 and iPad (10th generation)
7. Re-cloned the repo using Xcode's built in git clone feature

Comment: Doing `pod update` may be giving you a newer version of the pods than on the developer's machine. Have the original developer do `pod update` and see if they start having issues.

Comment: Strange indeed. Compare podfile.lock (to check the versions), are XCode the same versions? Are the iOS versions testing the same? Else, try to debug https://github.com/kukushi/SideMenu/blob/master/Sources/SideMenu/SideMenuController.swift and see why the value is not set. It seems that `myContentViewController()` or `myMenuViewController()` returns nil, why?

Comment: Also, to clarify your question, this is a runtime error, not a build error.  Your app is building successfully, but it is not running because one of the two arguments you have passed are nil.  Set a breakpoint on the `window?.rootViewController=...` and use the debugger to see which of those view controllers is `nil`. You can also set a breakpoint on line 172 of SideMenuController.swift and look at the call stack to see where the problem came from - It may be somewhere else in the app where you are creating an instance of this controller.

Comment: Also you say that you "added the function below" - Was that function not already in the code?  Are you, in fact, running different code to the other developer?  Regardless, since you have a runtime problem the debugger is going to be your friend here

Comment: @HangarRash Yes, you're right ```pod update``` does put me on higher version numbers, but even without updating the pods, I still have the same issue.

Comment: @Larme, forgot to add that, but I pulled up the podfile.lock on both machines and verified that every pod had the same version numbers.  The iOS and xcode version numbers are the same.  I look into the SideMenu code more tomorrow.

Comment: @Paulw11 Correct, this is a runtime error, the build is successful.  I added some print statements to help me debug but tomorrow I will go back and add breakpoints to see if I can catch anything I missed before.  And when I added the function, that was not a part of the original code.  I added that just to check if it was an issue with that pod or if it was an issue with the code itself.  I have it commented out now since I don't think that is going to help me since it was not a part of the original code.

Comment: "And when I added the function, that was not a part of the original code." So there is a difference. So to be clear: does the original code from the commit works? Only your changes makes it crash? Which are your changes exactly? What's the original code?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running a diff on the two repos and I found that the developer just deleted the part of the SideMenuSwift pod file that raised the nil error.